# How to make custom function more robust and less error prone

Tags: r, function, matrix

Here is my data:

```
LoDFs <- list(first = mtcars[, c(1:3)], second = mtcars[, c(4:6)])
row.names(LoDFs[[1]]) <- NULL
row.names(LoDFs[[2]]) <- NULL
```

Here is my function:

```
RollapplyMultipleFuncsAndWins <- function(df.val, df.name, window.size, funs, ..., GroupByWindowSize = TRUE){
  library(zoo) # REQUIRED FOR rollapply
  by.rows <- 1
  combinations  <- expand.grid(window.size, funs)
  combinations  <- cbind(combinations, rep(names(funs), each = length(window.size)))
  colnames(combinations) <- c("window.size", "func.call", "func.name")
  combinations$window.size <- sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(combinations$window.size)), "d"),
                                      combinations$window.size)

  LoMs <- apply(combinations, by.rows, function(x) {
                                                     rollapply(
                                                        df.val,
                                                        width = as.numeric(x[["window.size"]]),
                                                        by    = as.numeric(x[["window.size"]]),
                                                        FUN   = x[["func.call"]],
                                                        align = "left")})

  # COLUMN NAMING CONVENTION: column_name.function_name
  LoMs <- lapply(seq_along(LoMs), function(x) {
                                                colnames(LoMs[[x]]) <- paste(colnames(LoMs[[x]]),
                                                                             combinations$func.name[x],
                                                                             sep=".");
                                                LoMs[[x]] })

  # MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS WITH SAME WINDOW SIZE IN ONE DATASETS
  # LIST ELEMENTS NAMING CONVENTION: dataset_name.window_size
  if (GroupByWindowSize){
    df.win.grps <- lapply(unique(combinations$window.size), function(x) { grep(x, combinations$window.size) })
    LoMs        <- lapply(df.win.grps, function(x){ do.call(cbind, LoMs[x]) })

    names(LoMs) <- paste(rep(df.name, each=length(df.win.grps)),
                         unique(combinations$window.size),
                         sep=".")
  }
  # MULTIPLE FUNCTIONS WITH SAME WINDOW SIZE IN MULTIPLE DATASETS
  # LIST ELEMENTS NAMING CONVENTION: dataset_name.function_name.window_size
  else {
    names(LoMs) <- paste(rep(df.name, each=nrow(combinations)),
                         combinations$func.name,
                         combinations$window.size,
                         sep=".")
  }
  return(LoMs)
}
```

Purpose of this function is to apply multiple functions with multiple rollings/movings windows size over one dataset. It takes size of rollings/movings and functions as inputs and creates all possible combinations of those values. For example when you pass `c(2, 3, 10)` as `window.size` and `c(median = median, mean = mean)` as `funs` It will create following combinations (which says that `median` and `mean` will be called with rolling/moving window of size `2, 3, 10` for specified dataset):

```
  window.size                                         func.call func.name
1          02 function (x, na.rm = FALSE) , UseMethod("median")    median
2          03 function (x, na.rm = FALSE) , UseMethod("median")    median
3          10 function (x, na.rm = FALSE) , UseMethod("median")    median
4          02             function (x, ...) , UseMethod("mean")      mean
5          03             function (x, ...) , UseMethod("mean")      mean
6          10             function (x, ...) , UseMethod("mean")      mean
```

Function then returns list of matrices where each matrix corresponds to results obtained using particular window size including results from all functions (if `GroupByWindowSize` is `TRUE`) or list of matrices where each matrix corresponds to results obtained using particular window size and particular function (if `GroupByWindowSize` is `FALSE`). You can try e.g. following to better understand what I mean:

```
res_one_def     <- RollapplyMultipleFuncsAndWins(LoDFs[[1]], names(LoDFs)[1], c(2, 3), c(median = median, mean = mean))
res_one_non_def <- RollapplyMultipleFuncsAndWins(LoDFs[[1]], names(LoDFs)[1], c(2, 3), c(median = median, mean = mean), GroupByWindowSize=FALSE)
```

Problem is when I want same window size but multiple functions e.g.:

```
res_one_def     <- RollapplyMultipleFuncsAndWins(LoDFs[[1]], names(LoDFs)[1], c(1), c(median = median, mean = mean))
```

I've figured out that the problem is with calling `LoMs <- apply(combinations, by.rows, function(x) { ....` line. Instead of list of matrices (as it previously returns) it now returns one matrix and I do not know why (now the combinations is of same type as before just smaller):

```
  window.size                                         func.call func.name
1           1 function (x, na.rm = FALSE) , UseMethod("median")    median
2           1             function (x, ...) , UseMethod("mean")      mean
```

**Questions:**

1. Why I get the error described above?
2. If you check the code you can see that I'm building `combinations` as `expand.grid(window.size, funs)` but what if I want to being able to handle also `expand.grid(funs, window.size)` (notice reordered arguments) will `if (GroupByWindowSize){` branch correctly work also in this example (let's pretend that `combinations` will be passed as argument to function so I want to being able to handle various types)?
3. Is possible somehow define naming convention for list elements in the beginning of function and easily switch it from `dataset_name.window_size` to e.g. `dataset_name.function_name.window_size` in both if-else branches? As you can see now the `names(LoMs) ...` in both branches is very different, I'm curious if it is possible to make it unique somehow?
4. How can I make this code more robust and more generic in general, Is my approach correct or is there better way? Any ideas welcomed.